# Setting UITextView frame not working

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview, frame, cgrect

```
CGRect tempframe = _infoText.frame;
tempframe.size.height = _infoText.contentSize.height;
_infoText.frame = tempframe;
[_infoText sizeToFit];
CGFloat height = _infoText.frame.size.height;
CGFloat start = _infoText.frame.origin.y;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+start);
```

This is somehow giving me the correct size of the _scrollView but the _infoText (UITextView) is not changed EVEN though _infoText.frame.size.height is correct at this moment. Perhaps it's changing back to it's original size after? I'm doing all this code 0.1sec after -viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the containing view first. Otherwise the nested text view may be autoresized when its superview is resized. Also, don't call `sizeToFit` after setting the frame.

Comment: I changed it so that I call _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,height+start); before I set the _infoText.frame but this didn't change the outcome.